# gdb python scripting: where has `parse_and_eval` gone?

Tags: python, gdb

I had some scripts in Python to help me debugging with GDB that used the function [`gdb.parse_and_eval`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html#Basic-Python) (still documented) to get the inferior values from the arguments passed to a scripted command, and now the module doesn't seem to have any trace of that function. Doing `python import gdb; print dir(gdb)` from GDB clearly shows that this function is missing.

I wrote the scripts some time ago for the GDB 6.8 in the *archer* branch, and now I cannot find any information about if it's been deprecated or what happened in GDB 7.

Any information about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where it went or why, but Qt implemented this workaround in [their code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/commit/68bd4d2b95702046116a02b9fdc37a57983de011), which may be practically useful to you:

```
def parseAndEvaluate(exp):
        if gdb.VERSION.startswith("6.8.50.2009"):
            return gdb.parse_and_eval(exp)
        # Work around non-existing gdb.parse_and_eval as in released 7.0
        gdb.execute("set logging redirect on")
        gdb.execute("set logging on")
        gdb.execute("print %s" % exp)
        gdb.execute("set logging off")
        return gdb.history(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

`parse_and_eval` was checked in on the Archer branch, but has not been merged into mainline in time for 7.0 release. It has been merged now:

```
2009-12-03  Tom Tromey  <tromey@redhat.com>

        * python/python.c (gdbpy_parse_and_eval): New function.
        (GdbMethods): Add "parse_and_eval".
```

and will be available in the upcoming 7.1 release.