# Is there special significance to a comment starting as #~ in Python?

Tags: python, comments

What is this syntax used for in Python?:

```
#~ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I've run into this syntax a few times, for example in [this script](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/gdb-py/pygdb-nub.py) as referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947389/gdb-auto-stepping-automatic-printout-of-lines-while-free-running/6964213#6964213). For example:

```
def gdbExecute(exp):
  #~ if gdb.VERSION.startswith("6.8.50.2009"):
      #~ return gdb.parse_and_eval(exp)
  # Work around non-existing gdb.parse_and_eval as in released 7.0
  gdb.execute("set logging redirect on")
  gdb.execute("set logging on")
  locrep = gdb.execute("%s" % exp, True, True)
  gdb.execute("set logging off")
  return locrep
```

I attempted [this SymbolHound search](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%23~&p=2), but only came up with ~100 additional references where it's being used, but no direct explanation. There seem to be some indications that it's used for internationalization or translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default comment marker in [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html).

Default settings have:

```
comment.block.python=#~
```

And yes, it's a purely aesthetic choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special meaning *to Python* for comments starting with `#~`.

This is in all likelyhood a 3rd party tool using the `~` for their own purposes. I suspect there is an IDE used here that implements use this to do one of the following:

- a block-comment feature that lets you easily remove the commenting again, returning the lines to their formal state
- tell the IDE that the commented-out line can still be highlighted as code
- have the lines be executed when running with debugging enabled

or other such feature. *Or* it could just be a stylistic choice people make from time to time.

The comment style also shows up in [Ruby code](https://searchcode.com/?q=%23~&loc=0&loc2=10000&lan=32), so this is hardly unique to Python.